# javascript regex doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a register form. Naturally, every user have to choose a username and a password, but I want to, that there are only small a-z characters and numbers 0-9 in the usernames.
I want to use regex and javascript. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html lang="en-US">  
<head>  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
  <title></title>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    function check(value) {  
      valid_qwe = /[a-z0-9\-]$/;
      trying = valid_qwe.test(value);
      alert("The name: " + value + "\nBe allowed: " + trying);  
      return valid_qwe;  
    }
  </script>  
</head>  
<body>  
  <input type="text" autofocus id="qwe" name="qwe" value="" />  
  <input type="submit" onClick="check(document.getElementById('qwe').value);" value="Check" id="check" />  
</body>  
</html>
```

But when I'm trying to test e.g.: apple or #apple always write "true".

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't want `\-` after number but only `/[a-z0-9]$/;`

Comment: Restricting the alphabet available for user names and passwords is a security failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regexp tests if the last character is within those constraints, try using `/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
var valid_qwe = /^[a-z0-9-]+$/;
```

Three changes here:

- the pattern itself now is `one or more characters of the given range` (note that `+` quantifier after the brackets);
- it's anchored both to the end (with `$`) and the beginning (with `^`) of the string;
- no need to escape `-` within the character range if it's the last or the first symbol of it.

Finally, I'd rather see all the variables used within that function of yours localized - hence `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct (*except that you are checking the last character*), but you're not matching the full string.

Add a `+` to your regex, which means, match one or more of the previous token.

So your regex should be:

```
var valid_qwe = /[a-z0-9\-]+/
```